# Different API number for PHP extension

Tags: php, dll, php-extension

So this is the case, I am trying to develop an php-extension for my customers. I use SWIG for generating the wrapper code and my main code is c++. After I create my extension successfully I load it in /ext and restart the web server for testing it. I've got the error which mentioned that the extension has been built with API 20090626 but the PHP server(in my case XAMPP) API is 20100525. I totally understand the error, so I open the Zend_modules.h header file in php source and change the API number from 20090626 to 20100525, then I build my extension with updated zend_modules.h header file and now I have no problem.

The question is, my customers are using different php servers with different APIs for sure, and I planed to give them a dll (my extension) which can be loaded easily without any struggles. But now I should give them a VS2010 solution with my main code (dll) dynamically loaded. I mean each user should first check the PHP API from his own server and change the Zend_modules.h header file, build the solution and then use the extension. I need a solution which make my extension totally independent to that API number.

I really appreciate any idea.

Comment: What??!! php extensions in windows are dll !!

Comment: Ah, I'm a mac user, sorry! Stupid comment deleted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I totally understand the error, so I open the Zend_modules.h header file in php source and change the API number from 20090626 to 20100525

The fact that you're doing this tells me that you do not actually understand the error.

Modules are **NOT** compatible between different major versions of PHP -- the Zend API number is used to ensure that PHP does not inadvertently attempt to load a module that was built for a different version. The modifications that you're making to your PHP build tree are causing it to build modules that will not function correctly on any version at all.

If you need to build modules for multiple major versions of PHP, you need to run the builds using the corresponding version of PHP. You cannot mix and match, and you cannot build a single module that will work for multiple versions. (Nor should you advise your users to modify their PHP build to accept an incompatible module. That'll just make horrible things happen.)

The API versions for a few versions of PHP are listed below:

- PHP 5.2: 20060613
- PHP 5.3: 20090626
- PHP 5.4: 20100525
- PHP 5.5: 20120211

Comment: By the way, do you have any opinion of using my c++ functions in PHP without using extensions. I need a solution which can be version independent.

Comment: If your extension will only be used on Windows, you might be able to do something with the COM extension.

Comment: Do you happen to remember where you found these version numbers?