# my /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/xxx directory does not exist

Tags: php

when i check via phpinfo(), it says 'your extension library is: /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/**no-debug-non-zts-20090412**/

but, when i login via ssh...

```
cd /
cd /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/
ls
```

there is only **no-debug-non-zts-2010052**/ folder here... 
no **no-debug-non-zts-20090412**..

what should i do?

should i rename **no-debug-non-zts-2010052** to **no-debug-non-zts-20090412** ??

Comment: create it would be an option!

Comment: Enter "php --ini" in your console. It shows all configuration files which php uses. Then check where this extension is configured and change the path in that configuration. Restart apache afterwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number at the end of the directory name is the PHP API version. This version is related to the major version of PHP that the extensions are for ([I listed several such versions in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15171355/149341)). However, the API versions that you are mentioning in your question do not exist.

Assuming that you have simply mistyped the API versions involved, you will need to recompile your PHP extensions for the version of PHP that you are using. Without knowing the actual API versions from the error message, though, I can't say what the correct versions would be.

Comment: sorry.. it was an example.. phpinfo() gives 20100525, but there is only 20090626 folder is there..

Comment: See the answer I linked for what versions those correspond to.

Comment: yes.. i have php5.4 now.. and it points 20100525.. but, there is no 20100525 folder.. how can i fix the problem? should i rename 20090626 to 20100525?

Comment: You will need to recompile the extensions you need for PHP 5.4. Extensions are not compatible across PHP versions.

Comment: ok.. i should rebuild apache via easyapache i think.. thank you so much duskwuff..