# How do PHP releases match "API=yyyymmdd" signature/tag?

Tags: php, api, versioning

Is there a definite and reliable source to find out which PHP release version x.y.z carries/uses which "API=yyyymmdd" signature/tag?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The version control repository of PHP is the authoritative source on the correlation between PHP releases and their API date-versions. Keep in mind that only *major releases* of PHP (e.g. 7.4) have a unique date-version.

## new & improved

(for the lazy and irresponsible)

```
 curl https://gist.githubusercontent.com/tox2ik/8bafc9132fec4200312bc65005aec99c/raw/b7d921f157320b0cf451ae53577923bdf92801fc/ver.sh | bash
```

results in January 2021

```
$ time bash ver.sh 
php-4.0.3   19990421  4.0.3
php-4.0.6   20010119  4.0.6
php-4.2.3   20010901  4.2.3
php-4.4.9   20020918  4.4.9
php-5.0.5   20031224  5.0.5
php-5.2.17  20041225  5.2.17
php-5.3.29  20090626  5.3.29
php-5.4.45  20100412  5.4.45
php-5.5.38  20121113  5.5.38
php-5.6.40  20131106  5.6.40
php-7.0.33  20151012  7.0.33
php-7.1.33  20160303  7.1.33
php-7.2.34  20170718  7.2.34
php-7.3.27  20180731  7.3.27
php-7.4.15  20190902  7.4.15
php-8.0.2   20200930  8.0.2
time: Real 0m1.1s  User 0m0.8s  System 0m0.7s
```

script to run from the php git repo:

```
$ cat ver.sh 
git tag \
  | grep -Eo 'php-([0-9]+\.?){3}$' \
  | sort -ut. -k1.5,1n -k2,2n -k3,3n \
  | while read tag; do
  echo $tag `
  git show $tag:main/php.h | sed -n ' /#define PHP_API_VERSION /{ s///; p; q } '
  ` `
  git show $tag:main/php_version.h | sed -n " /#define PHP_VERSION /{ s///; s/[\"']//g; p; q } "
  `
done \
 | awk '{ ap[$2]=$0 } END { for (i in ap) { print ap[i] } }' \
 | column -t
```

remove the last awk part to list all x.y.z releases.

---

original answer below

---

(assuming bash)

Fetch PHP.

```
git clone https://github.com/php/php-src.git
cd php-src
```

list of relevant tags

```
tags() {
    git tag |
    sed -En ' /(RC|alpha|beta)/d ; /php-5/p ; ' | 
    sort -t. -k1,1n -k2,2n -k3,3n
}
```

some 270 log entries for main/php.h (where API version is defined).

```
go_crazy() {
    git log  main/php.h | 
    awk '/^commit / { print $2 }' | 
    tac
}
```

match relevant lines and remove cruft.

```
api() { 
    sed -n ' /#define PHP_API_VERSION /{
        s///; p; q } ' main/php.h
}

php_version () { 
    sed -n " /#define PHP_VERSION /{ 
        s///; 
        s/[\"']//g; 
        p; q 
    } " main/php_version.h
}
```

do the doo!

```
for i in `tags`
do
    
    git co -f $i
    echo $i `api`

done  > /tmp/tag.apis; 

for i in `go_crazy`
do
    
    git co -f $i
    echo `php_version` `api`

done > /tmp/many.versions
```

## Results

```
$ awk '{ print $2, $1 }' /tmp/many.versions /tmp/tag.apis  | sort -u -k1,1
19990421 4.0pa1
20010119 4.0.5-dev
20010901 4.0.8-dev
20020307 4.3.0-dev
20020918 4.3.0-dev
20030518 5.0.0-dev
20030820 5.0.0b2-dev
20031103 5.0.0b3-dev
20031224 5.0.0RC1-dev
20041225 5.1.0-dev
20090626 5.3.0
20100412 5.3.99-dev
20121113 5.5.0-dev
20131106 5.6.0-dev
20131218 5.7.0-dev
 4.0pa1
 php-5.0.1b1
```

## For the curious

Versions starting with php- are git tags and presumably official releases.

```
$ awk 'NF==2 { print $2, $1 }' /tmp/tag.apis /tmp/many.versions  | sort 
  
19990421 4.0.0
19990421 4.0.1
19990421 4.0.1-dev
19990421 4.0.1-dev
19990421 4.0.1-dev
19990421 4.0.1-dev
19990421 4.0.1-dev
19990421 4.0.1-dev
19990421 4.0.1-dev
19990421 4.0.1-dev
19990421 4.0.1-dev
19990421 4.0.1-dev
19990421 4.0.1-dev
19990421 4.0.1-dev
19990421 4.0.2
19990421 4.0.2
19990421 4.0.2-dev
19990421 4.0.2-dev
19990421 4.0.2-dev
19990421 4.0.2-dev
19990421 4.0.2-dev
19990421 4.0.2-dev
19990421 4.0.2-dev
19990421 4.0.2-dev
19990421 4.0.2-dev
19990421 4.0.2-dev
19990421 4.0.2-dev
19990421 4.0.2-dev
19990421 4.0.2-dev
19990421 4.0.2-dev
19990421 4.0.2-dev
19990421 4.0.2-dev
19990421 4.0.3-dev
19990421 4.0.4-dev
19990421 4.0.4-dev
19990421 4.0.5-dev
19990421 4.0.5-dev
19990421 4.0B1
19990421 4.0B2
19990421 4.0b2-dev
19990421 4.0b2-dev
19990421 4.0b2-dev
19990421 4.0B3-dev
19990421 4.0B3-dev
19990421 4.0B3-dev
19990421 4.0B3-dev
19990421 4.0B3-dev
19990421 4.0B3-dev
19990421 4.0B3-dev
19990421 4.0B3-dev
19990421 4.0B3-dev
19990421 4.0B3-dev
19990421 4.0B3-dev
19990421 4.0B3-dev
19990421 4.0B3-dev
19990421 4.0B3-dev
19990421 4.0B3-dev
19990421 4.0B3-dev
19990421 4.0B3-RC2
19990421 4.0b3-RC5
19990421 4.0b3-RC5
19990421 4.0b4-dev
19990421 4.0b4-dev
19990421 4.0b4-dev
19990421 4.0b4-dev
19990421 4.0b4-dev
19990421 4.0b4-dev
19990421 4.0b4-dev
19990421 4.0b4-dev
19990421 4.0b4-dev
19990421 4.0b4-dev
19990421 4.0b4-dev
19990421 4.0b4-dev
19990421 4.0b4-dev
19990421 4.0b4-dev
19990421 4.0b4-dev
19990421 4.0b4-dev
19990421 4.0b4-dev
19990421 4.0b4-dev
19990421 4.0b4-dev
19990421 4.0b4-dev
19990421 4.0b4-rc1
19990421 4.0b5-dev
19990421 4.0b5-dev
19990421 4.0b5-dev
19990421 4.0b5-dev
19990421 4.0b5-dev
19990421 4.0b5-dev
19990421 4.0b5-dev
19990421 4.0pa1
19990421 4.0pa1
19990421 4.0pa1
19990421 4.0pa1
19990421 4.0pa1
19990421 4.0pa1
19990421 4.0pa1
19990421 4.0pa1
19990421 4.0pa1
19990421 4.0pa1
19990421 4.0pa1
19990421 4.0pa1
19990421 4.0RC1
19990421 4.0RC1
19990421 4.0RC2
19990421 4.0RC2-dev
19990421 4.0RC2-dev
19990421 4.0RC2-dev
19990421 4.0RC2-dev
19990421 4.0RC2-dev
19990421 4.0RC2-dev
19990421 4.0RC2-dev
19990421 4.0RC2-dev
19990421 4.0RC2-dev
19990421 4.0RC2-dev
19990421 4.0RC2-dev
19990421 4.0RC2-dev
19990421 4.0RC2-dev
19990421 4.0RC2-dev
19990421 4.0RC2-dev
19990421 4.0RC2-dev
19990421 4.0RC2-dev
20010119 4.0.5-dev
20010119 4.0.5-dev
20010119 4.0.5-dev
20010119 4.0.5-dev
20010119 4.0.5-dev
20010119 4.0.6-dev
20010119 4.0.6-dev
20010119 4.0.6-dev
20010119 4.0.7-dev
20010119 4.0.7-dev
20010119 4.0.7-dev
20010119 4.0.7-dev
20010119 4.0.7-dev
20010119 4.0.7-dev
20010119 4.0.7-dev
20010119 4.0.7-dev
20010119 4.0.7-dev
20010119 4.0.7-dev
20010119 4.0.7-dev
20010119 4.0.7-dev
20010119 4.0.7-dev
20010119 4.0.7-dev
20010119 4.0.7-dev
20010119 4.0.7-dev
20010119 4.0.7-dev
20010901 4.0.8-dev
20010901 4.0.8-dev
20010901 4.0.8-dev
20010901 4.2.0-dev
20010901 4.2.1-dev
20010901 4.2.1-dev
20010901 4.2.1-dev
20010901 4.2.1-dev
20010901 4.2.1-dev
20010901 4.2.1-dev
20010901 4.3.0-dev
20010901 4.3.0-dev
20010901 4.3.0-dev
20010901 4.3.0-dev
20010901 4.3.0-dev
20020307 4.3.0-dev
20020307 4.3.0-dev
20020307 4.3.0-dev
20020307 4.3.0-dev
20020307 4.3.0-dev
20020307 4.3.0-dev
20020307 4.3.0-dev
20020307 4.3.0-dev
20020918 4.3.0-dev
20020918 4.4.0-dev
20020918 4.4.0-dev
20020918 5.0.0-dev
20020918 5.0.0-dev
20020918 5.0.0-dev
20020918 5.0.0-dev
20020918 5.0.0-dev
20020918 5.0.0-dev
20020918 5.0.0-dev
20030518 5.0.0b2-dev
20030518 5.0.0b2-dev
20030518 5.0.0-dev
20030518 5.0.0-dev
20030518 5.0.0-dev
20030518 php-5.0.0b1
20030820 5.0.0b2-dev
20030820 5.0.0b2-dev
20030820 5.0.0b2-dev
20030820 5.0.0b2-dev
20030820 5.0.0b2-dev
20030820 5.0.0b2-dev
20030820 5.0.0b2-dev
20030820 php-5.0.0b2
20031103 5.0.0b3-dev
20031103 php-5.0.0b3
20031224 5.0.0RC1-dev
20031224 5.0.0RC1-dev
20031224 5.0.0RC1-dev
20031224 5.1.0-dev
20031224 5.1.0-dev
20031224 5.1.0-dev
20031224 5.1.0-dev
20031224 5.1.0-dev
20031224 5.1.0-dev
20031224 php-5.0.0
20031224 php-5.0.0b4
20031224 php-5.0.1
20031224 php-5.0.2
20031224 php-5.0.3
20031224 php-5.0.4
20031224 php-5.0.5
20041225 5.1.0-dev
20041225 5.1.0-dev
20041225 5.1.0-dev
20041225 5.1.0-dev
20041225 5.1.0-dev
20041225 5.1.0-dev
20041225 5.1.0-dev
20041225 5.1.0-dev
20041225 5.1.0-dev
20041225 5.1.0-dev
20041225 5.1.0-dev
20041225 5.1.0-dev
20041225 5.1.2-dev
20041225 5.1.2RC2-dev
20041225 5.1.3-dev
20041225 5.1.3-dev
20041225 5.2.0-dev
20041225 5.2.0-dev
20041225 5.2.0RC4-dev
20041225 5.2.1-dev
20041225 5.2.1-dev
20041225 5.2.1RC2-dev
20041225 5.2.1RC2-dev
20041225 5.2.5-dev
20041225 5.3.0alpha2-dev
20041225 5.3.0alpha2-dev
20041225 5.3.0alpha2-dev
20041225 5.3.0alpha2-dev
20041225 5.3.0alpha2-dev
20041225 5.3.0alpha3-dev
20041225 5.3.0alpha4-dev
20041225 5.3.0-dev
20041225 5.3.0-dev
20041225 5.3.0-dev
20041225 5.3.0-dev
20041225 5.3.0-dev
20041225 php-5.1.0
20041225 php-5.1.0b1
20041225 php-5.1.0b2
20041225 php-5.1.0b3
20041225 php-5.1.1
20041225 php-5.1.2
20041225 php-5.1.3
20041225 php-5.1.4
20041225 php-5.1.5
20041225 php-5.1.6
20041225 php-5.2.0
20041225 php-5.2.1
20041225 php-5.2.10
20041225 php-5.2.11
20041225 php-5.2.12
20041225 php-5.2.13
20041225 php-5.2.14
20041225 php-5.2.15
20041225 php-5.2.16
20041225 php-5.2.17
20041225 php-5.2.2
20041225 php-5.2.3
20041225 php-5.2.4
20041225 php-5.2.5
20041225 php-5.2.6
20041225 php-5.2.7
20041225 php-5.2.8
20041225 php-5.2.9
20090626 5.3.0
20090626 5.3.3-dev
20090626 5.3.3-dev
20090626 5.3.3-dev
20090626 5.3.3-dev
20090626 5.3.3-dev
20090626 5.3.99-dev
20090626 php-5.3.0
20090626 php-5.3.1
20090626 php-5.3.10
20090626 php-5.3.11
20090626 php-5.3.12
20090626 php-5.3.13
20090626 php-5.3.14
20090626 php-5.3.15
20090626 php-5.3.16
20090626 php-5.3.17
20090626 php-5.3.18
20090626 php-5.3.19
20090626 php-5.3.2
20090626 php-5.3.20
20090626 php-5.3.21
20090626 php-5.3.22
20090626 php-5.3.23
20090626 php-5.3.24
20090626 php-5.3.25
20090626 php-5.3.26
20090626 php-5.3.27
20090626 php-5.3.28
20090626 php-5.3.3
20090626 php-5.3.4
20090626 php-5.3.5
20090626 php-5.3.6
20090626 php-5.3.7
20090626 php-5.3.8
20090626 php-5.3.9
20100412 5.3.99-dev
20100412 5.3.99-dev
20100412 5.3.99-dev
20100412 5.3.99-dev
20100412 5.3.99-dev
20100412 5.3.99-dev
20100412 5.5.0-dev
20100412 5.5.0-dev
20100412 5.5.0-dev
20100412 5.5.0-dev
20100412 5.5.0-dev
20100412 php-5.4.0
20100412 php-5.4.1
20100412 php-5.4.10
20100412 php-5.4.11
20100412 php-5.4.12
20100412 php-5.4.13
20100412 php-5.4.14
20100412 php-5.4.15
20100412 php-5.4.16
20100412 php-5.4.17
20100412 php-5.4.18
20100412 php-5.4.19
20100412 php-5.4.2
20100412 php-5.4.20
20100412 php-5.4.21
20100412 php-5.4.22
20100412 php-5.4.23
20100412 php-5.4.24
20100412 php-5.4.25
20100412 php-5.4.26
20100412 php-5.4.3
20100412 php-5.4.4
20100412 php-5.4.5
20100412 php-5.4.6
20100412 php-5.4.7
20100412 php-5.4.8
20100412 php-5.4.9
20121113 5.5.0-dev
20121113 5.5.0-dev
20121113 5.6.0-dev
20121113 5.6.0-dev
20121113 php-5.5.0
20121113 php-5.5.1
20121113 php-5.5.10
20121113 php-5.5.2
20121113 php-5.5.3
20121113 php-5.5.4
20121113 php-5.5.5
20121113 php-5.5.6
20121113 php-5.5.7
20121113 php-5.5.8
20121113 php-5.5.9
20131106 5.6.0-dev
20131106 5.6.0-dev
20131106 5.6.0-dev
20131106 5.6.0-dev
20131218 5.7.0-dev
20131218 5.7.0-dev
20131218 5.7.0-dev
```

Comment: My 2 cents:

PHP Extension 20121212
PHP Version 5.5.6

Answer (score 3):

I've looked for such a thing in the past, but haven't found any really good sources. (Searching for some of the API versions shows [a post I made a while back listing them](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15171355/149341) as one of the top hits!) Here are all of the recent ones:

- PHP 5.2: 20060613
- PHP 5.3: 20090626
- PHP 5.4: 20100525
- PHP 5.5: 20120211
- PHP 5.6: 20131226 (as of 5.6.0alpha3)

Comment: So you want to say these are the result of your personal research?

Comment: I have to admit it didn't even came to my mind to scan SO for any of those tags. I somehow had the (naive?) idea I would find an authoritative answer at places like php.org or zend.org.

Comment: Personal research? I suppose. You can find them by digging through old versions of the PHP source, but I haven't found a compilation like this anywhere else. BTW, by "searching", I actually mean a general Google search, not just StackOverflow!

Comment: Looking at your list one could get the impression that all micro releases to a certain minor release share the same sigature. Would you tend to confirm this?

Comment: @alk: This is true for all recent non-development releases of PHP. (It was not true for some older versions, though.) Changing the API version requires extensions to be rebuilt, so it's something the PHP developers are trying to avoid.

Comment: Interesting decrepancies between your list and the list in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22139183/694576

Comment: Interesting indeed. The API version I have for 5.5 may have been for a development version. API version 20060613 is definitely out there, though (the number shows up all over Google), and it's not attested at all in Ярослав's answer.

Comment: My guess is that some author of a (popular) third party PHP extension got tired of waiting (after two years) for version bump to the API and built his stuff off an unofficial PHP fork. -- Either that or some popular vendor Ubuntu / Debian / Redhat / XAMPP released a PHP package with a non-official API version.

Comment: I have trouble believing that there was no API version bump at all between PHP 5.1 and 5.2, though.

Comment: duskwuff how does your list correspond to the list shown in Ярослав Рахматуллин's answer? For example, for PHP 5.5, the date you have is 20120211 but in the last list in Ярослав Рахматуллин's, the date given is 20121113 for php-5.5.0. I'm not saying either of you are wrong; I'm sure you're both correct but I don't know why the dates are different. Thanks.