# Apache start cannot run pthreads extension

Tags: php, pthreads

I tried to include pthreads in php.ini as follows:

```
  extension=ext/php_pthreads.dll
```

However, it prompts the message when I start apache, I checked the PHP config, it is 5.5.10 
and thread safety is enabled. Seems the PHP is alreadt Thread Safe. Do I need to recompile the PHP with --enable-zts config?

The error message is:

```
PHP Startup: 
pthreads: Unable to initialize module. 
Module compiled with module API=20131226 . 
PHP compiled with module API=20121212. 
These options need to match.
```

Comment: You probably need to downgrade `php_pthreads.dll` to match the version of the php module you are using, The DLL's signature points to being version 5.6, where as php's signature seems to be 5.5. You might like to check this answer (http://stackoverflow.com/a/22139183/694576) for a quiet detailed mapping of signatures to versions.

Answer (score -1):

please check that php_pthreads.dll exists in you xampp extension directory.

if it's not exists download and paste it there and then restart xampp.

your problem must be fixed.

Comment: From the error message it is quiet obvious that this is not an issue of missing files but of mismatching version of the compoments involved.